# vb.net Display/Focus/Show Form on top of PC Game

Tags: vb.net

What I am trying to accomplish is this: I want to be able to press the F5 key on my keyboard, while playing a PC game, to show (bring forward, focus, etc.) my program. My 3 attempts so far have failed. Any idea on how I could accomplish my goal? Similar posts on other forums say to set the form's key preview to true and use on keyPress... which failed.

Thank you,
Anonymous

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set HotKey system-wide in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194752/how-to-set-hotkey-system-wide-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the question about [capturing global mouse / keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112949/capture-and-send-keyboard-mouse-input-in-c), you can try using it in VB.NET and test it, though I guess you only don't want to be caught while playing games during work. ;)

Also I definitely suggest this **[link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/globalmousekeyboardlib.aspx)** from it. :)